# Typing a function that can accept/return N array of items with rest/spread generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have a lot of arrays that store objects of key/value pairs for dropdowns and other items in our app.

We also use `next-i18next` for our translations and I'm trying to create a helper function that can receive `1...n` of these, transform the values to use the translation function and destructure them in a single line, as opposed to calling the hook multiple times

```
type OptionType = { text: string, value: string };

const untransformedMap1: OptionType[] = [
  { text: 'settings:preferences', value: 'preferences' },
  { ... }
]; 

// eg:
const [map1, map2, ...] = useAddTranslationsToOpts(untransformedMap1, untransformedMap2, ...);

// instead of
const map1 = useAddTranslationsToOpts(untransformedMap1);
const map2 = useAddTranslationsToOpts(untransformedMap2);
// ...
```

so far what I have:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

function useAddTranslationsToOptions<T extends OptionType[]>(...opts: T[]): [...T] {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const arr: T[] = [];
    opts.forEach((map: T) => {
        const transformed = map.reduce((acc: T, item) => [...acc, { text: t(item.text), value: item.value }], []);
        arr.push(transformed)
    });
    return arr;
}
```

this isn't working but I think should give an idea of what I'm after here? Haven't got my head around rest spread tuple types yet but I would imagine they would solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after exactly, but maybe this helps:

```
function useAddTranslationsToOptions<T extends OptionType>(...opts: T[][]): T[][] {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const arr: T[][] = [];
    opts.forEach((map: T[]) => {
        const transformed = map.reduce<T[]>((acc, item) => [...acc, { ...item, text: t(item.text) }], []);
        arr.push(transformed)
    });
    return arr;
}
```

One of the problems was that `{ text: t(item.text), value: item.value }` is not compatible with `T` (although it is with `OptionType`).
This can be solved by using the spread operator which will add all keys and values of `item` to make it compatible with `T`:

```
{ ...item, text: t(item.text) }
```

Comment: yeah this works well enough with the return type as `T[][]`. Thanks